# Typeahead: show ALL results instead of exact string matches

Tags: typeahead.js, typeahead

I have an input box to search for products. It uses typeahead to fetch and display the returned data.

A problem arises when the ajax response contains results that does not exactly match my input value. 
For example:

```
input query = "daffalgane"

JSON data result is = 
{products: 
         { id:100, label: "dafalgan 500" },
         { id:101, label: "dafalgan 750mg" },
         { id:500, label: "daffalgane 600 mg" },
}
```

Typeahead only displays the one with id:500, since it has an exact(part of the) string match.

Why are the other results not displayed? It would make more sense to me that typehead would just display the returned dataset.

For reference, this is the config used for the input box:

```
 $('#suggestions').typeahead({
    minLength: 1,
    maxItem: 10,
    hint: false,
    highlight: false,
    emptyTemplate: 'NO RESULTS',
    source:{
        products: {
            display: "label",
            href: baseurl+'{{slug}}',
            url: [{
                type: "POST",
                url: baseurl+'/suggest',
                data: {
                    for: "{{query}}".trim()
                },
            }, "data.products"],

        },
   }});
```

Comment: what is the value in `query`?

Comment: @whipdancer The value in query is "daffalgane". Appearantly, typeahead performs its own filtering on the source dataset based on the query value.

Since I already have a filtered data, I just need it to display the entire source, without the extra filtering done by typeahead.

Comment: Most typeaheads (it seems) will perform an exact match, and then will find anything that is similar based on the text you type.  Because you've typed in daff, the others will not match.  The more characters you type, the more explicit your match becomes.  Depending on which typeahead you are using, you might be able to provide your own search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by upgrading to typeahead version 2.3.4 (http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/)
and setting the filter parameter to false.

This prevents the filtering on the results done by typeahead and just displays the source.